# Clean Way to Fill Third Dimension of Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array representing an RGB image. I would like to fill the whole image with a particular RGB value. `numpy.fill` only takes a scalar as an argument-- is there a cleaner way than looping to assign the same third-dimension RGB triplet to each point in the 2d grid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe:

```
>>> m = np.zeros((2,2,3))
>>> m[:] = [10,20,3]
>>> m
array([[[ 10.,  20.,   3.],
        [ 10.,  20.,   3.]],

       [[ 10.,  20.,   3.],
        [ 10.,  20.,   3.]]])
>>> m[0,0]
array([ 10.,  20.,   3.])
>>> m[0,1]
array([ 10.,  20.,   3.])
>>> m[1,0]
array([ 10.,  20.,   3.])
>>> m[1,1]
array([ 10.,  20.,   3.])
```

Answer (score 3):

Initialize the array

```
In [2]: m = numpy.zeros((2,2,3))

In [3]: m
Out[3]: 
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

Fill out each (x, y) element with an (r, g, b) triplet

```
In [22]: m[...] = (11, 22, 33)

In [23]: m
Out[23]: 
array([[[ 11.,  22.,  33.],
        [ 11.,  22.,  33.]],

       [[ 11.,  22.,  33.],
        [ 11.,  22.,  33.]]])
```

Is this what you want to do?

Also, if you want to set, say, only green component

```
In [25]: m[..., 0] = 77

In [26]: m
Out[26]: 
array([[[ 77.,  22.,  33.],
        [ 77.,  22.,  33.]],

       [[ 77.,  22.,  33.],
        [ 77.,  22.,  33.]]])
```

Comment: I want to basically do this, but instead of `[11, 22, 33]` I want random numbers generated in a specific way (here: a function with random noise on top). If i'd do `m[...] = np.random(3)`, i'd always have the same three random numbers. If I'd do `m = np.random((2, 2, 3))`, i'd have to little control over how the random numbers are generated. Of course, I don't want for-loops. Do you have an idea?

Comment: You can assign an array too, e.g. `m[..., 0] = [1, 2, 3, 4]` it has to be correct size and data is up to you.